# How to save schema and definition of my database into MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, semantic-web

I am designing a very flexible platform to gather semantic data and create a semantic database using python and MongoDB.

i need a way to store the flexible schema in my database, so my python app would read the schema from db, and provide appropriate forms for data insertion.

i need an standard style like what Mongoose does have to define my schema and store it in mongodb database.
something like:

```
person: {
  name: {
    type: String
       }

  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    lowercase: true,
    }

  children: {
    type: array (array of persons!!)**
    }
}
```

one of my problems is how to store relational schema in an standard way.
and how to manage the schema and update it using python.

ill appreciate if you could show me a project, website, article or anything that could show me how can i do it in an standard way.

Comment: Are you looking for http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/defining-documents.html?highlight=schema ?

Comment: @Mani Mongo Engine is great but it stores the schema as python classes. what i need is to store the schema as a mongodb collection, or documents in a jsonic or bsonic style INTO the same mongodb database and read the schema FROM database and create dynamic models from it, in python.

Comment: MongoDB natively provides support for schemas https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/234869/172114

Comment: Thank you @Mani i read the documents about validations. it could hep me a lot but yet i didn't found how should i define relations.

Comment: You don't define relations. MongoDB really does not support relations. It provides a method to `$lookup` data from another collection and return a "joined" result, but there is not "relational shcema" or "referential integrity" or any of those things, and **this is by design**. The `Validation` provided by MongoDB is completely optional and can be either loose or strict. But there is basically **no schema here**, and that is for your application to define, if you so choose. But again, there is no **need** for an application to even have a "set" schema. And that's basically the point.

Comment: As for the question itself about "storing and loading schema definition data", then **at best** this is **too broad**, and at worst it borders on **asking for recommedations** of possible existing libraries or tools.